# Mysql Incremental Backup and point in time recovery

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm writing a shell script using the **concept of binary logs** for point in time recovery.

Now, the scenario is such that a **full-backup will happen every alternate day** and **Incremental backup should be done in between**.
Suppose full-backup happens on Monday and Wednesday, incremental backup should happen on Tuesday.
For point in time recovery, I'm using **`mysqlbinlog --starttime --stoptime binary-logs > backup.sql`**
In the shell script I need to use starttime and log position of the previous full-backup to specify the log files in the statement, how can I retrieve this in a shell script and record the changes done during that time.
Is there anyway I can do this, please help me in this regard.

Comment: How will you be making your "incremental" backup?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Incrementalbackup happens using mysqlbinlog. The log files and start time and end time are calculated from last backup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlincrementalbackup/ script. Description from its website:

> A complete incremental backup for MyISAM and InnodB in a mix
>   environment for those applications use both of engines simultaneously
>   using binary logs and a method that does not affect running database.
>   There is no need to stop or lock the database, It does utilize only
>   binary logs to extract update queries of databases. This tools uses
>   automysqlbackup script as part of solution for its full backup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it’s more correct not to try to find out the start date for the `--starttime` parameter, but simply to submit the first binlog that appeared right after the full backup that was created.

To do this, you have to create a full backup in the correct way.

A full backup should be created using the following parameters:

```
mysqldump --flush-log --master-data=2
```

`--flush-log` - creates a new binary log consistent with the data in the full backup (it should be restored right after the full backup).

`--master-data=2` - writes the name of the binlog file that was created by the `--flush-log` option at the very beginning of the full backup. The dump will show a line similar to this:

```
-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.002927', MASTER_LOG_POS=120;
```

Thus, before restoring, you simply open a full backup, check and restore only those binlogs whose numbers are equal or higher than specified in the CHANGE MASTER TO... line.

Here are a couple of articles on how to backup and restore incremental MySQL backups [on Windows](https://blog.sqlbackupandftp.com/mysql-incremental-backups-on-windows) and [on Linux](https://blog.sqlbak.com/incremental-mysql-server-backup-via-binary-log)