# How to do point in time recovery of binary log files into .sql file

Tags: mysql, backup, permissions, recovery

I have written a shell script to do an incremental backup of MySQL database.
For **point in time recovery** I'm using the binary logs generated in /var/lib/mysql directory.
For **point-in-time recovery**, Im creating an sql file using the following statement.

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="$STARTTIME" --stop-datetime="$ENDTIME" $file > $NOW.test.sql
```

The incremental backup happens such that the **$STARTTIME** is going to be the **end time of the Fullbackup** and **$file** is the **list of log files generated since the fullbackup endtime to the time of start of incremental backup**.
My question is how can I create a .sql file in /var/lib/mysql folder and move that file to the destination .
When I try the above statement, it says permission denied. How can i achieve this?
I know the permissions for the file has to be changed. Is there any alternative for this.

Comment: how you are planing point in time recovery script. I means on what basis you are writing the script to find out last bin log file position and current bin log file,position.

Comment: @ashuthosh  **NEWFULLLOG=`ls -d /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.??????| sed 's/^.*\.//'| sort -g| tail -n 1`**

Comment: I changed permissions of that directory ....it is working now

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
STARTTIME="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
ENDTIME="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
TEMP_DIR="/path/to/temp/dir"
FINAL_DEST="/var/lib/mysql"
BINLOG_PATH="/var/lib/mysql"

# Ensure TEMP_DIR exists
mkdir -p "$TEMP_DIR"

# Generate SQL from binary logs
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="$STARTTIME" --stop-datetime="$ENDTIME" "${BINLOG_PATH}/mysql-bin.*" > "${TEMP_DIR}/${NOW}.test.sql"

# Move SQL file to the desired location (requires appropriate permissions)
# Option 1: Using sudo to move the file (if you have sudo privileges)
sudo mv "${TEMP_DIR}/${NOW}.test.sql" "${FINAL_DEST}/"

# Option 2: Change ownership and move the file (if you do not have sudo privileges but have access to the mysql user)
# chown mysql:mysql "${TEMP_DIR}/${NOW}.test.sql"
# mv "${TEMP_DIR}/${NOW}.test.sql" "${FINAL_DEST}/"

echo "Point-in-Time recovery file created and moved successfully."
```